# Is possible to deactivate the possibility to edit filter in a report in the Lightning experience?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, reporting, profile, filters

Is possible to deactivate the possibility to edit filter in a report in the Lightning experience? Or at least "lock" every filter?

Our users does not create/edit/delete a report. Some of them can access reports because the admin shares a folder in view mode.

Below you can see that 3 of 4 filters can not be locked.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image: only this filter can be 'locked']

Answer (score 0):

When adding or editing a filter in lightning experience, there is a Locked checkbox right below the type and value inputs. Selecting it will ensure that the filter will not be editable on the run page.

See this trailhead https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/rd-filter-report-data/rd-filter-the-report.

Comment: I update my question with some pictures. only the fourth filter can be locked.